# How to write something vertically below another math symbol

Tags: math-mode

I have to write some equations in latex, but I'm having trouble finishing them.

[image: Image 1]

My Latex equation for image 1:

```
\widehat{f}(x,y)=median \left\{g(s,t)\right\}
```

[image: Image 2]

My Latex equation for image 2:

```
A\oplus B = U A_{b}
```

How can I make a subscript below the formulas?

Comment: Are you sure it's a `U` in the second example? I'd say it's `\bigcup_{b\in B}`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You want

```
\hat{f}(x,y) = \underset{(s,t)\in S_{xy}}{\mathrm{median}} \{g(s,t)\}
```

And

```
A \oplus B = \underset{b\in B}{\cup} A_b
```

The important things being:

- `\underset` which takes two arguments, the first is put under the second.
- `\mathrm` to make `median` appear upright and differentiate it from a multiplication of 6 variables named m, e, d, i, a, and n.
- `\{` and `\}` need backslashes because `{` and `}` are part of the LaTeX base language.
- `\cup` which is a nicer symbol for a union.

Comment: How about this one "g(x,y)=\begin{cases}1 & If s  hits f\\ 0 & otherwise\end{cases}".
How to add space between "if s hits f"??

Comment: @FarhatMann This is another question. Please post a new one in these cases. Anyway the answer is `g(x,y)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{If $s$ hits $f$}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}` and requires the package `amsmath`

Comment: How to make it displayed in center of the pages? Because if i write the equation, it will display in the left side of the page.

Answer (score 24):

at least the first example is a case where limits are applied to an operator.  using `amsmath`, put this in the preamble:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\median}{median}
```

and enter the math expression as

```
\[ \hat{f}(x,y)= \median_{(s,t)\in S_{xy}} \left\{g(s,t)\right\} \]
```

with this result:

[image: output of example code]

`\DeclareMathOperator` will set the specified string as roman, although other alphabet styles can be specified; the starred version causes strings designated as sub- or superscripts to the operator to be set as limits.

for the second example, it's reasonable to treat this the same way, but specifying italic:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Uoperator}{\mathit{U}}
```

then `... \Uoperator_{b\in B} ...` would yield the requested result.

Comment: This answer is nice because it lets you put the arguments both above and below the expression, whereas using underset/overset you can only do one of the two, not both.

Comment: @Chill2Macht \overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\bigwedge}} works well for me. 
The sugested \DeclareMathOperator* did not work.

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov-- I'm not able to test this at present, but `\DeclareMathOperator*` is designed to support limits on its argument -- but only in display mode.  (Limits would appear to the side in text mode.)  This *does* require `amsmath`.  Since this doesn't work for you, please ask a separate question, providing a complete compilable example showing what you are doing, and cite this question and answer in yours, describing exactly what is different in what you are doing.

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\median}{median}
\begin{document}
\[ \hat{f}(x,y)= \median_{(s,t)\in S_{xy}} \left\{g(s,t)\right\} \]
\end{document}` works beautifully on my machine.